# What kind of assembly instruction is this ld1 {v0.16b}, %[in]?

Tags: assembly, neon, arm64

This instruction is an ARMv8 neon instruction but I'm not able to understand the elements of it. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: Syntax reference: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1427897530197.html

Comment: Related: [what does `vst1.64 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r4:128]!` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386861/what-vst-vld-actually-do)

Answer (score 2):

This is not called NEON anymore, the SIMD instructions are part of the armv8 standard set.

- ld1 is the instruction: load single from memory into vector register
- v0.16b is the register name and type: first SIMD register, 16 bytes
- %[in] is the address in memory (probably a symbolic name for inline assembly)

So, you load a single register (16 bytes) from a memory location specified by the %[in] parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction is an ARMv8 Load-Store Multiple Structure; which is an Advanced SIMD instruction.

LD1 - loads multiple 1-element structures

v0 - vector register 0 in this case, could be v1, v2,...

.16b -  indicates you are loading 16 (1 byte) elements from memory. This can be 8 or 4H(alve words) or 8H... See the manual for more.

%[n] - I don't know what (%) is for; however, if you're using the instruction directly (i.e., not as an inline, etc) then [] - contains your vector address/pointer or the register holding array address.

In my partial code sample below, you will see a sample array in the .data section. A pointer in x10. The load instruction of 16 single byte elements, then proof of the load in a gdb print statement.

I compiled with gcc; therefore, other compilers may require a different syntax. 
 #armv8 #simd

```
.data
array: .byte 7,3,1,6,7,1,7,6,5,3,1,3,3,0,6,2,4,9,1,9,2,2,5,1,1,9,6,7,4,4,2,6,5,7,4,7,4,2,3,5,5,3,4,9,1,9,4,9,3,4
...
ldr x10,=array
...
// Load multiple 1-element structures (to one register)
ld1 {v0.16b}, [x10] // load 16 byte values into vector 0 
...
(gdb) p $v0.b.s
$4 = {7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2}
```

Comment: G B's answer is almost certainly right about `%[in]`.  It probably comes from GNU C inline asm syntax, like `char *input, *output; ...; asm ("ld1 {v0.16b}, %[in]\n"  "...use v0\n" : [out] "m" (*output) : [in] "m" (*input));`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands

Comment: What is an "n-element structure"?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ARM NEON programming quick reference](http://community.arm.com/groups/android-community/blog/2015/03/27/arm-neon-programming-quick-reference), we learn:

- The general form of a NEON instruction is `{<prefix>}<op>{<suffix>} Vd.<T>, Vn.<T>, Vm.<T>`.
- `v0` is a 128-bit NEON vector register
- The `.16b` matches the `<T>` part, which means "type" (`16B` means 16 bytes, i.e. the full 128 bits are being used).

The `in` part probably comes from surrounding C code.