# What VST/VLD actually do?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

What exactly will happen with below 2 lines of code?

```
vst1.64 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r4:128]!
vst1.64 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r4:128]
```

More generally, I want to know what VST & VLD do since doc from:
[ARM InfoCenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/ch05s145.html) doesn't make it clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vst1.64 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r4:128]!
```

This instruction stores the content of the registers d8, d9, d10 and d11 at the location pointed by r4. This location is hinted to be aligned to a 128 bit boundary. Afterwards r4 will be incremented by the amount of bytes stored. These would be 32 (four times 8 bytes) in your case

```
vst1.64 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r4:128]
```

This instruction does the same as the above but stores d12, d13, d14 and d15. R4 will not be incremented but left where it is.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the there are severe restrictions on the valid patterns for the list of registers.  From the linked doc, they either have to be 4 contiguous registers, or with a stride of 2.  So you can't shuffle for free with a store like `vst1.64 {d9, d8, d11, d10}, [dst]`.  I assume the machine encoding just encodes the first register, and one more bit for stride=1 or 2.

Comment: @Nils Pipenbrinch Thank you. But would you please make it more clear? For example: how content from d8,d9,d10,d11 will be used to store to r4 and what is the meaning of .64 followed by vst1?

Comment: This does not store to `r4` but to the memory location at address `r4`. `.64` is the element size. For a `vst1` it does not have much impact (Except in some cases alignment and endianism) but it would have more impact on `vst2`, `vst3` or `vst4` while deinterleave structures before storing to memory.